# Complex for each loop

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a large data set with the prices for finished goods and then the prices of the items that make up that finished good. I am trying to write a code in VBA that would allow me to compare the price of the finished good to the total of the items making up the finished good. Only problem is that the finished goods have a different number of items in them so it makes it hard to grab the two since they are not always the same number of rows away from each other. So, my question is there a way to make two identifiers next to the numbers then have the code grab the numbers next to it and compare. Below is just a couple of the finished goods and their items. I was thinking that I could write a for each loop so if I make the identifiers it can loop the comparing process. I just started learning VBA and this way over my head so if any of you have an idea of how to make this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
W0003662    1537244 1           DUCTWORK 42148 14X8 VOLUME DAM  $4.25   $0.00 
            1648481 1   5X7 POLY BAG-4ML. 1/4 HANG HOL          $0.09   $0.09 
            1653390 1   PP WINDSOR HDL -LG - SMOKE ONL          $3.00   $0.00 
            44135   1   CPVC RED TEE 3/4X3/4X1/2" CTS           $0.72   $0.00 
                        TRC 
    Total Rep   Cost........    .......:                        $3.82


W0000312    1642273 1           PACKING WASHER ASST / 10266 $0.21   $0.21 
            1642263 1   501 SOLUTION PACKING / 10253        $0.05   $0.05 
            1642264 1   502 SOLUTION PACKING / 10254        $0.05   $0.07 
            1642265 1   503 SOLUTION PACKING / 10255        $0.05   $0.05 
            1642266 1   504 SOLUTION PACKING / 10256        $0.05   $0.05 
            1648471 1   3X4 POLY BAG-4ML. 1/4 HANG HOL      $0.01   $0.01 
                        _________   
    Total Rep   Cost........    .......:                    $0.21   


W0000316    1642329 1           ISE CONNECTION CLAMP & FLEX CO  $3.84   $3.84 
            1648475 1   4X6 POLY BAG 4ML.SEAL TOP 1/4           $0.02   $0.02 
            1652000 1   ISE CONNECTION CLAMP / ISE7470          $0.61   $0.61 
            1652001 1   INSINKERATOR FLEX COUPLING / I          $3.21   $3.21 
                        _________   
    Total Rep   Cost........    .......:                        $3.84   

W0002538    1642335 1           WHIRLAWAY DISP.SPLASH GUARD /   $0.57   $0.57 
            1648475 1   4X6 POLY BAG 4ML.SEAL TOP 1/4           $0.02   $0.02 
            1642336 1   WHIRLAWAY DISP.SPLASH GUARD X           $0.55   $0.55 
                        _________   
    Total Rep   Cost........    .......:                        $0.57
```

VBA code:

```
Sub CompareWipCost()
Dim TRC As Range
Dim test_wip As Worksheet
Set test_wip = ActiveSheet
Set TRC = Selection

For Each TRC In test_wip

    If TRC.Offset(1, 0).Value = 3.815 Then
        With Selection.Interior
            .Color = 65535
        End With
    Else
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is definitely something that is doable (even if hairy, give your data layout). But you'll have to find the pattern, code for it and create a [mcve] showing where you are stuck. As written this question is simply too broad to help with at the moment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I'd start by writing yourself some pseudocode so that you understand the logic before you try to translate it into VBA. You've got three different sorts of line: 1.totals (with 'Total Rep   Cost'), 2.detail first line (first character nonblank), 3.detail subsequent line (anything else that isn't completely blank). So run through the lines: if 1., pull out total value, compare to current cumulated sum; if 2., initialise sum with item value; if 3., add item value to current cumulated sum. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you writing my ideas down as helped a little bit and I will keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick awful thought (note change "sheet2" to reflect the name of your sheet)

```
Dim r As Variant

Sub main()
  r = Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange                         'capture data into array r
    For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)                       'loop through array
      If InStr(r(i, 1), "W000") > 0 Then                 'signal start of first data set
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(r)                       'loop until "total rep" is found
          If InStr(r(j, 1), "Total Rep") > 0 Then        
            For k = i To j
              'do something awesome with the data here
              Debug.Print r(k, 1)
            Next k
          ElseIf InStr(r(j, 1), "W000") Then Exit For    'exit on next loop
          End If
        Next j
      End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight I'll look into this to see if I can make this work but I dont need to loop to find total rep cost as it given to me in the first rows with the w000. So, im looking for away to compare 4.25 to 3.82 then flag it if they dont match but as you see the range between those two numbers changes

Comment: The way the data is pasted on the question makes it a bit difficult for comparison - not sure if it's a cell reference or just tab delimited but you can take out the k loop and compare r(j, columnNumber) to r(i, columnNumber) to make that determination and flag if they're <> (not equal)

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try and do some research into arrays so I can get a better understanding of how to fix my problem.

Comment: you don't necessarily have to load it into an array, it just ends up being tons faster, also arrays = good imho. :) keep your locals window open to the right, step through the script using f8, expand out the array to see what it looks like.  HTH Good luck! happy scripting